# Get "Resources exceeded during query execution" in the middle of daily batch job

Tags: python, resources, google-bigquery

For bigquery python client, has already configured as using standard SQL

```
query_job = self.client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), query_str)
query_job.use_query_cache = True     #  query cache 
query_job.use_legacy_sql = False
```

however, when sending the query, get the following 400 errors in the middle of batch job -  complaining resources exceeded during the execution. The query is rather simple one - to get timely ordered rows within 30 minutes range in a daily partitioned table (each day has about 40 million rows, total 15-20G data). Since each query cover 30 minutes' range, the same query would run 48 times to cover a single day. Each query returns 500k - 1.5 million row, data amount is in the range of hundreds' MBs. The following query was executed well initially, but only after 10-20 iteration, `RESOURCES exceeds` error would pop up.

Can bigquery gurus, experts, developers who got the same issues before help give some hints what might going wrong here. Really appreciated!

Roy

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  client_ip,
  url,
  req_ts,
  req_body,
  resp_body,
  status
FROM
  xxxx.table
WHERE
  DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = '2017-09-16'
  AND req_ts >= '2017-09-16 15:30:00'
  AND req_ts < '2017-09-16 16:00:00' order by req_ts



File "../datastore/bigquery.py", line 202, in sendQuery

    query_job.result()  #Wait for job to complete

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 492, in result

    return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api/core/future/polling.py", line 104, in result

    self._blocking_poll(timeout=timeout)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api/core/future/polling.py", line 84, in _blocking_poll

    retry_(self._done_or_raise)()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api/core/retry.py", line 258, in retry_wrapped_func

    on_error=on_error,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api/core/retry.py", line 175, in retry_target

    return target()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api/core/future/polling.py", line 62, in _done_or_raise

    if not self.done():

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 1301, in done

    self._query_results = self._client.get_query_results(self.name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 196, in get_query_results

    method='GET', path=path, query_params=extra_params)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request

    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)

BadRequest: 400 GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/fluted-house-161501/queries/ab8534f8-fe52-448c-84fe-b8702ee7b87c?maxResults=0: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in ORDER BY which causes whole result to be moved to one worker for final ordering before outputting result. If result is big enough this usually causes "Resources exceeded during query execution"

Recommendation here is either add LIMIT with some reasonable number  - in this case - partial ordering happens on all workers and final ordering is made on one node but now for quite reduced result or just remove ORDER BY at all and do your ordering on client side

See more about ORDER BY at [`Order query operations to maximize performance`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#order_query_operations_to_maximize_performance) Take a look at second paragraph

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It's actually the 'order by' causing the query problem.  After I removed it from where clause, the query can actually be executed with no further problem. We would just need to add some extra work to deal with the partial ordering  from the query results. Appreciate for the help and reference!